# AngularJS Material Tab height issue

Tags: angular-material

I'm having some troube figuring things out with AngularJS Material, I was wondering if anyone knew why the folling piece of code:

```
<md-tabs layout-fill >

    <md-tab id="tab1">
        <md-tab-label>Item One</md-tab-label>
        <md-tab-body>

            <md-list>
                <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">3 line item</md-subheader>
                <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,50]">

                    <div class="md-list-item-text">
                        <h3>sdfs</h3>
                        <h4>sdfsd</h4>
                        <p>sdfsdf</p>
                    </div>
                </md-list-item>

            </md-list>
        </md-tab-body>
    </md-tab>

</md-tabs>
```

produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMB9G.jpg) on firefox.

and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YALrj.jpg) on chrome.

sorry about not posting images directly I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: and there is still no solution for this probably...

Answer (score 27):

I also Had a similar issue. Though `md-dynamic-height` solved it...

You can try using:

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height>
  <md-tab>
    <md-tab-label>Tab label</md-tab-label>
    <md-tab-body>
      <md-content>The tab content</md-content>
    </md-tab-body>
  </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

Comment: I love you. Thank you so much. ( Yes, we're using AngularJS in 2018, kill me )

Comment: @Baruch I can feel your pain bro!

Comment: @Baruch It's 2023 and unfortunately we're still using AngularJS so I know exactly what you mean 

Answer (score 4):

If the issue you're trying to solve is that the tabs do not take up the full available height:

1. As far as I know, it's impossible to do this via existing md attributes (and I've spent hours researching this)
2. It will not be fixed by the team anytime soon (see comment from ThomasBurleson on June 10, 2016 here: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2254)
3. Here is a way to fix this that worked for me:

   Make sure every parent element has `layout="column"` and `layout-fill` attributes
   (or `layout-column` and `layout-fill` classes).  This includes
   `<ng-outlet>` if that's relevant for your use case.

IMPORTANT NOTE ABOUT CUSTOM COMPONENTS CREATED VIA COMPONENT ROUTER:

In my case my html structure is ng-outlet -> custom-component -> md-card -> md-tabs

I added `layout="column"` and `layout-fill` to `<ng-outlet>` and `<md-card>` and added `layout="column"` to `<md-tabs>`.  However, I couldn't find a way to add them to `<account-component>` (because it's created dynamically by Angular) so what I ended up doing is adding this (somewhat hacky) code to my component controller (ES6 but should be understandable even if you write ES5):

```
import template from './account.html';

export const accountComponent = {
    template: template,
    controller: accountController,
};

/*@ngInject*/
function accountController (accountService) {
    this.data = accountService.getAccountData();

    /*** THIS IS THE HACKY PART THAT SOLVED IT FOR ME: ***/
    this.$routerOnActivate = function () { // nextRoute
        const classes = document.querySelector('account-component').classList;
        classes.add('layout-column');
        classes.add('layout-fill');
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `layout-fill` will work as you intend in this case because the md-tab specifies a header and content, whereas I think you want the content to expand to fill the parent.

You might want to try adding the `md-dynamic-height` option to the `md-tabs` directive which should force angular-material to set a consistent height to the tab(s).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass attribute 'md-dynamic-height' to yr md-tabs directive.
Below code will work fine.

```
  <md-content layout="column">
      <md-tabs md-dynamic-height flex>

        <md-tab id="tab1">
          <md-tab-label>Item One</md-tab-label>
          <md-tab-body>
            <md-list>
              <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">3 line item</md-subheader>
              <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,50]">
                <div class="md-list-item-text">
                  <h3>sdfs</h3>
                  <h4>sdfsd</h4>
                  <p>sdfsdf</p>
                </div>
              </md-list-item>
            </md-list>
          </md-tab-body>
        </md-tab>

        <md-tab id="tab2">
          <md-tab-label>Item Two</md-tab-label>
          <md-tab-body>
            <md-list>
              <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">3 line item</md-subheader>
              <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,50]">
                <div class="md-list-item-text">
                  <h3>sdfs</h3>
                  <h4>sdfsd</h4>
                  <p>sdfsdf</p>
                </div>
              </md-list-item>
            </md-list>
         </md-tab-body>
        </md-tab>

  </md-tabs>   
 </md-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<md-tabs  class="md-primary" md-selected="leadDetailsTab" md-dynamic-height>
 <md-tab label="First tab">
    <div ng-include="'/src/widgets/test.html'"></div>
 </md-tab>
 <md-tab label="Second tab">
    <h1>Second tab data</h1>            
 </md-tab>
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).